# Trying to use beginTarnsaction() and commit() but it fails when I put the commands in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a little confused as to why this doesn't work, as so far as I can tell, I've done nothing different to various other examples I've seen.

If I run the following code;

```
try{
    //Set the connection
    $db = new PDO($dbcon, $user, $pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //Start Transaction
    $db->beginTransation();

    //SQL to insert Basic Info
    $sql1 = //Insert statement here
    $query1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
    $query1->execute(array(...));

    //Run the SQL commands above
    $db->commit();

    //Set success message
    $return['message'] = 'success';
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $db->rollback();
    $return['message'] = "Error:  ".$e; 
};


//$return = $_POST;
$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);
```

Then my update fails.  If I run the same command without the begin/commit lines;

```
try{
    //Set the connection
    $db = new PDO($dbcon, $user, $pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //SQL to insert Basic Info
    $sql1 = //Insert Statement Here
    $query1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
    $query1->execute(...));

    //Set success message
    $return['message'] = 'success';
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    $db->rollback();
    $return['message'] = "Error:  ".$e; 
};


//$return = $_POST;
$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);
```

Then the insert works fine.

I've seen various exmaples (mostly on this site, though also from various other sites), which have the `$db = new PDO...` and the `$db->setAttrib...` lines outside of the try catch block (which I've tried and it didn't help).

Other than that, as far as I can see, everything in my code lines up with other peoples examples, which apparently work.

I'm very new to PDO's, and this is the first time I've every tried to use the `beginTransation()` and `commit()`.

I should also point out that in my example,I I've only added a single update, but in reality there are 5 update statements on 5 different tables, which are all dependant on the previous table update working.  This is why I want to use begin/commit, as I believe I can then use `$db->rollback();` in my catch to undo everything in case of an error (at least that is how I understand it??)

I'd very much like it if someone could point out the mistakes I'm making (or at least point me in the right direction), as I'm sure they are really obvious and I'm missing something really basic!

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I've edited the codes above, to remove some information that I don't think other people needed to see (things like my database connection details, and the exact insert statements being used).

Comment: Do you have any error returned?

Comment: side note: you're embedding json-in-json, which is invariably a mistake. you build one SINGLE array structure in php, then encode the entire thing. not individual parts and then the entire thing yet again - that's just double-encoding.

Comment: @D4V1D - No error that I can see (though that's probably just because of the way I'm implementing things).

Comment: @MarcB - What do you mean by embedding json-in-json??  Can you explain where I've gone wrong??  This page gets called (ajax) from another php page, and at the minute I'm simply returning a json encoded 'success' or 'fail' message (or at least trying to) to the original php page, which I'm then alerting to see if my inserts are working (which they don't with the begin/commit.

Comment: you encode a string, then embed that encoded string in ANOTHER array and encode that array. that's double-encoding. you'd end up with `{"foo":"{\"bar\":\"baz\"}"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some more examples, and after a lot of messing around, I have now got a block of code that works (note that I've removed the actual insert statements in my code below).

I don't know what changed, since I'm sure I'd tried this layout before, but I'm willing to assume that there was a typo in my code originally, which I've managed to correct in my various trials.

The full code layout (with actual statements removed as stated above) was;

```
//Set the connection
$db = new PDO($dbcon, $user, $pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try{
    //Start Transaction
    $db->beginTransaction();

    //SQL to insert Basic Info
    $sql1 = //Insert Statement Here
    $query1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
    $query1->execute();    //With parameters

    //Set member_id variable
    $member_id = $db->lastInsertId();

    //SQL to insert Address Info
    $sql2 = //
    $query2 = $db->prepare($sql2);
    $query2->execute();    //With parameters

    //SQL to insert Medical Info
    $sql3 = 
    $query3 = $db->prepare($sql3);
    $query3->execute();    //With parameters

    //SQL to insert Ethnicity and Disability Info
    $sql4 = 
    $query4 = $db->prepare($sql4);
    $query4->execute();    //With parameters

    //SQL to insert Declaration Info
    $sql5 = 
    $query5 = $db->prepare($sql5);
    $query5->execute();    //With parameters

    //Run the SQL commands above
    $db->commit();

    //Set success message
    $return['message'] = 'Database Updated Correctly';

}catch (PDOException $exception){
    $db->rollBack();
    $return['message'] = 'Fail: '.$exception;
};

//$return = $_POST;
$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);
```

Interestingly the `rollBack();` doesn't work in this example, but if I can't figure that one out, it will be another question.  (Incidentally, if I do figure out why `rollback();` doesn't work, I'll update this answer for future visitors)!